# How to get frequency of each value in two columns in a mapping table

Tags: sql, plsql

We have a mapping table with two columns, SITE_FROM & SITE_TO, the data is like:

[image]

We want to run a query to summarize for each site, get count in the SITE_FROM column and count in the SITE_TO column, such as:

[image] <- desired

The explanation is, S1 appeared 2 times in SITE_FROM, 2 times in SITE_TO. S2 appeared 3 times in SITE_FROM, 4 times in SITE_TO. S3 appears 0 times in SITE_FROM, 3 times in SITE_TO...

I came up with some query:

```
SELECT SITE_FROM AS SITE,
count(*) CNT,
count(decode(SITE_TO,'S1',1)) S1,
count(decode(SITE_TO,'S2',1)) S2,
count(decode(SITE_TO,'S3',1)) S3,
count(decode(SITE_TO,'S4',1)) S4,
count(decode(SITE_TO,'S5',1)) S5
FROM site_changes
GROUP BY SITE_FROM
ORDER BY 1
;
```

But it returns detailed site to site mapping, also it has to have hard coded values in it, if later more sites are added, we need to remember to update the query as well:

[image] <- undesired

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First get a defined list of all sites by unironing the data from site for each column.  (CTE BELOW)  this allows for any site to be added (no hard coding)
- then join the CTE to CITE for from and to and count with group by.
- since the left join will result in NULLS when no matches are found, and nulls do not get counted we should get the desired counts.

DEMO: https://dbfiddle.uk/k3ehGbIt

```
CTE AS (SELECT SITE_FROM as SITE FROM SITE_CHANGES
    UNION
    SELECT SITE_TO FROM SITE_CHANGES)



SELECT A.SITE, 
       coalesce(SUM(B.SITE_FROM_CNT),0) as SITE_FROM, 
       coalesce(SUM(C.SITE_TO_CNT) ,0) as SITE_TO
FROM CTE A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SITE_FROM, count(SITE_FROM) SITE_FROM_CNT 
           FROM SITE_CHANGES 
           GROUP BY SITE_FROM) B
 on A.SITE= B.SITE_FROM
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SITE_TO, count(SITE_TO) SITE_TO_CNT 
           FROM SITE_CHANGES 
           GROUP BY SITE_TO) C
 on A.SITE = C.SITE_TO
GROUP BY A.SITE
ORDER BY A.SITE
```

Giving us:

```
+------+-----------+---------+
| SITE | SITE_FROM | SITE_TO |
+------+-----------+---------+
| S1   |         2 |       2 |
| S2   |         3 |       4 |
| S3   |         0 |       3 |
| S4   |         4 |       1 |
| S5   |         1 |       0 |
+------+-----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I union'd both sets to get the full permutation of to and from site id's.  Then joined into that set twice with left outer joins.  To avoid nulls I used NVL replacing the null with 0.

```
SELECT
SITE
, NVL(Z.SITE_FROM,0) SITE_FROM
, NVL(A.SITE_TO,0) SITE_TO
FROM
(
SELECT sitefrom SITE
FROM
site_changes
UNION
SELECT siteto SITE
from site_changes
)  X
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) SITE_FROM, SITEFROM FROM site_changes GROUP BY SITEFROM
) Z ON X.SITE = Z.SITEFROM
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT COUNT(1) SITE_TO, SITETO FROM site_changes GROUP BY SITETO
)  A ON X.SITE = A.SITETO
```

Comment: you could do a full outer join between Z and A and skip building X altogether

Comment: I don't know if I like that solution, that might be incredibly slow if the data set is large.  @onepan

Comment: really? I'd have thought there's no difference between finding all distinct elements and then left joining vs full outer joining to start.

Comment: @onepan working in BI I have to do a lot of FULL OUTER and I find that the process time is slow, but maybe it's the DBMS I am on.  If you wouldn't mind post your solution as an answer I would like to look at how you would go about this.  The other answer was a union as well but in a common table expression.

Comment: sure, done. I'm not an expert on query compilation or anything, so I'd love to know more on what goes wrong in my case.

Answer (score 1):

The challenge is not having the same sites on both columns so we `unpivot` them to get a list of all the info and then `pivot` them back with `count` to get the info we need.

```
select   *
from     t
unpivot  (site for to_from in ("SITE FROM","SITE TO")) 
pivot    (count(*) for to_from in('SITE FROM' as "SITE FROM", 'SITE TO' as "SITE TO")) p
order by site
```

| SITE | SITE FROM | SITE TO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | 2 | 2 |
| S2 | 3 | 4 |
| S3 | 0 | 3 |
| S4 | 4 | 1 |
| S5 | 1 | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gDn0zYrt)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the same concept, but using a `full outer join` instead of selecting out the distinct elements.

```
with sf as (
  select
    site_from as site,
    count(*) as site_from
  from site_changes
  group by
    site_from
),
st as (
  select
    site_to as site,
    count(*) as site_to
  from site_changes
  group by
    site_to
)
select 
  site,
  nvl(site_from, 0) as site_from,
  nvl(site_to, 0) as site_to
from sf
full outer join st
  using (site)
```

@vlookup indicated that using `FULL OUTER JOIN` might be less performant. If you have a chance to compare the queries, please share the results.

Comment: you are using a CTE.  From my experiences, when using them with massive data sets the performance is crippling.  Just inserting results into a temp table I find to be much faster.  I would be curious to see how slow this query performs (assuming they are querying large data).  if you are dealing with fact  / dimensions (tuned) or small tables the performance hit will be tiny.